# react-native redux Login Form throws an 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined''

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

> ```
> This error is located at: 
>     in Item (at connectStyle.js:384)
>     in Styled(Item) (at LoginForm.js:56)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>     in View (at Form.js:10)
>     in Form (at connectStyle.js:384)
>     in Styled(Form) (at LoginForm.js:55)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>     in View (at View.js:9)
>     in ViewNB (at connectStyle.js:384)
>     in Styled(ViewNB) (at LoginForm.js:54)
>     in LoginForm (created by Connect(LoginForm))
>     in Connect(LoginForm) (at App.js:24)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>     in View (at ScrollView.js:717)
>     in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:811)
>     in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareScrollView.js:27)
>     in KeyboardAwareScrollView (at Content.js:10)
>     in Content (at connectStyle.js:384)
>     in Styled(Content) (at App.js:23)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>     in View (at Container.js:15)
>     in Container (at connectStyle.js:384)
>     in Styled(Container) (at App.js:21)
>     in Provider (at App.js:20)
>     in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>     in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
>     in RCTView (at View.js:71)
>     in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
>     in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
> <unknown>
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\Item.js:36:13
> Function.remove
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\native-base\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:6997:12
> Item.componentWillReceiveProps
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\Item.js:35:17
> callComponentWillReceiveProps
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5936:13
> updateClassInstance
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:6134:6
> updateClassComponent
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7827:21
> beginWork
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8284:15
> performUnitOfWork
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10513:15
> workLoop
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10584:25
> Object._invokeGuardedCallback
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\React\ProfilesApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:134:9
> ```

Here is is my Login Form

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';
import { Form, Item, Input, Label, Button,Text, View} from 'native-base';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged } from '../actions';
import { passwordChanged } from '../actions';
class LoginForm extends Component {

    onEmailChange(text) {

        this.props.emailChanged(text); // Calling the action creator
    }
    passwordChange(text) {
        this.props.passwordChanged(text);
    }
render() {
    return (
        <View>
    <Form style={styles.form}>
        <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>email</Label>
            <Input onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.email}
             />
            }
        </Item>
        <Item floatingLabel last>
            <Label>Password</Label>
            <Input secureTextEntry
             onChangeText={this.passwordChange.bind(this)}
            />
        </Item>
    </Form>

    </View>
    );
}   

}


const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,

    };
};
export default  connect(mapStateToProps , {emailChanged})(LoginForm);
```

My AuthReducer

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) => {
    console.log(action.payload);
    switch (action.type) {
        case EMAIL_CHANGED :

         return { ...state, email: action.payload};
        default: 
        return state;
    }
}
```

Action Creator

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED } from './types';
export const emailChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
        payload: text
    }
}
```

I don't get this error when empty my onEmailChange(text) function, which calls in the action creator. Is that problem related to native-base? Am I doing something wrong with my action creator?

Edit: I forgot to add, I get this error everytime I type into the input field

Comment: where you use the redux? Why you need to do bind in the event?

Comment: Make sure the record you are trying to access actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It's a rogue brace inside my render function

```
  <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>email</Label>
            <Input onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
            value={this.props.email}
             />
            }  <----
        </Item>
```